# Is there a way to set break point to make program stop at call instruction to a particular function?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, jit

I am debugging some JIT'ed code. I attach `gdb` to a running process. I am looking for ways to set a break point (or any other way) which would make the `gdb` break/pause at each `call instruction` to a particular function. I know the function name.

Note: I can set a break point on the taken branch for the `call instruction` i.e. the gdb breaks at the function but I want that the debugger should break before taking that branch i.e. at the `call instruction`.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: This is very hard bordering on impossible. There are many ways of calling a function, and they may not always use the `call` instruction – in particular if your function was in tail position. If a function pointer to your JITed code is taken, it may conceivably be called from anywhere. And just enumerating the location of `call` instructions is impossible – they may not yet have been JITed! I'd like to point out that by simply looking at the return address pushed on the stack by `call`, you _may_ be able to find your caller (provided, again, that tail call optimization did not occur).

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: Why not make this an answer?

Comment: the typical method is to set the break on the beginning of the function, (using 'br functionname')  then when the code breaks, use the back trace (bt) to display where/what called that function.  To note,  Not much useful info will be displayed unless 1) the source code is available, 2) the code with compiled (for gcc) with -g or -gdb  it is also best to not use any optimization, so code and line numbers in the source will lineup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want that the debugger should break before taking that branch

But why? Stopping before the branch is taken (as opposed to stopping immediately after) provides you absolutely no additional info.

As Iwillnotexist Idonotexist correctly pointed out, there are many ways to CALL a given function, e.g.

```
CALL 0x8(%rax)
CALL %rbx
CALL *0x12345678
```

In addition, in JITted code, such call instructions may get generated and discarded at very high rate, so even if you could magically find them all, you'd still need to refresh your list of breakpoints to set whenever your JIT feels like it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you also look at a related question I asked in a different post and give your inputs on that. Thanks again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656270/how-do-you-go-about-knowing-what-is-happening-in-a-jited-code