# How do you go about knowing what is happening in a JIT'ed code?

Tags: debugging, firefox, reverse-engineering, jit, disassembly

I am working with Firefox on a research project. Firefox makes uses of lots of `JIT'ed` code during run time.

I instrumented Firefox using a custom `PIN tool` to find out locations(address) of some things I as looking for. The issue is that those location are in `JIT'ed` code. I want to know what is actually happening over there in the code.

To do this I dumped the corresponding memory region and used `objdump` to disassemble the dump.
I used `objdump -D -b binary -mi386 file.dump` to see the instructions that would have been executed. To my surprise the only section listed is `.data` section (a very big one).

Either i am incorrectly disassembling it or something else is wrong with my understanding. I expect to see more sections like `.text` where actual executable instructions should be present and `.data` section should not be executable.

Am I correct in my understanding here?

Also If some one can please advise me on how to properly know what is happening in `Jit'ed` code.

Machine
`Linux 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP x86_64`

Comment: If you are really talking about JITed code, that means it's dynamically generated and thus won't be part of the executable-image. It will just be in memory marked executable, for example with [`mprotect`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> or something else is wrong with my understanding

Yes: something else is wrong with your understanding.

Sections (such as `.text` and `.data`) only make sense at static link time (the static linker groups `.text` from multiple `.o` files together into a single `.text` in the final executable). They are not useful, and in fact could be completely stripped, at execution time. On ELF systems, all that you need at runtime are segments (`PT_LOAD` segments in particular), which you can see with `readelf -l binary`.

Sections in ELF file are "parts of the file". When you dump *memory*, sections don't make any sense to even talk about.

The `.data` that you see in `objdump` output is not really there either, it's just an artifact that `objdump` manufactures.

Comment: Thanks a lot once again. So that means I can just interpret the instructions as shown by the objdump and try to figure out what is happening here. I mean objdump disassembly is fine in this case.